# Emacs ESS major mode font colour change after Error

Tags: emacs, ess

When using the R console through the ESS major mode in emacs, I encounter the following problem:

[Changed font color after Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUmV7.png)

The font color of all text, except for explicitly highlighted text such as links and Errors, changes from the default light color to dark, which is not easily visible in my theme. It starts after an Error. More specifically, the first line with the darker font color starts with "Run".

[Highlighted text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qSvG9.png)

Is there a way to remedy this? It persists until I execute "Reload process" and refresh my console session.

EDIT: Note a hack was found to avoid R from printing the output that causes this issue: https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/issues/1193

Comment: See this - https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/issues/1199#issuecomment-1144181944, I believe it's the same issue (happening with ESS and Emacs 28). Note: this solution by Fuco1 is the same as in the ilnk in the original post.